# How to add all the shopify filters to standard liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, liquid

We're using liquid in a web app.  I've noticed Shopify have implemented some useful filters which are not included by default in the liquid gem.  For example [url_param_escape](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#url_param_escape)

To test it I did this:

$irb

> require 'liquid'
>   Liquid::Template.parse('{{ " & " | url_param_escape }} ').render
>    => " &  "

Clearly these filters are not included by default. Are they available from somewhere?  If so where and how do I add them to the parser?  Otherwise is t a case of implementing them all one by one or are they all coming from the same module or something?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the `url_param_escape` filter. I have tried several others (remove, upcase, append) and they all work. But the url param escape does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for testing these Albin,  all of the ones on this list work:  https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers but not all of the ones listed here: https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can/must write them yourself. They're easy to create. Here's an example implementation of the url_param_escape filter:

```
module MyApp
  module Liquid
    module Filters
      module UrlParamFilter
        def url_param_escape(thing_to_escape)
          CGI.escape(thing_to_escape)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you'll need to register this filter so that Liquid knows to use it. I usually do this in application.rb inside config.after_initialize but there's probably a better place it can go if you have a lot of them. Here's an example of that:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ::Liquid::Template.register_filter(MyApp::Liquid::Filters::UrlParamFilter)
end
```